# jsonb, поиск по нескольким значениям

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, jsonb

Этот запрос выведет мне записи у которых есть поле first с id 1 и это работает:

```
User.where("first @> ?", {id: 1}.to_json)
```

Но мне нужно в id засунуть массив значений:

```
User.where("first @> ?", {id: [1,2]}.to_json)
```

и это возвращает пустой массив. При этом запись как минимум с одним id из массива присутствует в базе.
Из документации по jsonb запросам в postgresql это считается рабочим решением. Не понимаю, что идёт не так.
postgresql v10.9

Answer (score 1):

```
User.where("first->'id' IN (?)", ['1', '2'])
```

Comment: Возможно, ответ правильный, но, пожалуйста, поясните его. Для того, чтобы внести улучшающую правку, Вы можете воспользоваться кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1006608/edit). В будущем, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более осмысленные ответы. — [из очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/386497)